# How to integrate ACL to Azure Databricks based Azure AD groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, databricks, acl, azure-databricks

I have few tables created in Databricks workspace and I want to give read access to these tables for certain members.
Currently we can create groups in Databricks Workspace and provide SQL Workspace access, Cluster Creation permission.

Is it possible that I can add an Azure AD security group as a user in Databricks and control access to it rather than creating groups in databricks workspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add AAD group as a user of the workspace - you just need to sync necessary AAD groups and users from them into the Databricks workspace.  You can do that using one of the tools:

- [Azure Databricks SCIM Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/scim/aad) that will sync groups & users automatically
- Combine user & group resources of the [Databricks Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/user) with [Azure AD Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs) - with it you can easily pull groups & users from AAD, and apply these data to create users & groups in Databricks.
- Use [Databricks SCIM REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/) to provision users - you'll need to script it.

P.S. It's also usually not recommended to give users cluster creation permissions, otherwise the costs will be out of the control.  Instead, just create shared clusters, and SQL endpoints.  Or at least create a [cluster policy](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/clusters/policies.html) with predefined rules about cluster size, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot @AlexOtt
This really helped